# jQuery FileUpload script add additional POST

Tags: jquery, file-upload, multipart

I am using this script https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for multiple file (image) upload. It works great, however I would like to add an additional textbox to the form to post for each file. In the Options it has an example, but I can't seem to get it working. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options the example is the formData:
It seems to be using .tmpl() from jQuery to populate some columns. Also it looks like its using JSON to post the data. I have managed to add another JSON parameter, but cannot seem to get the $_POST['desc'] from each individual file upload. I am not sure if its even possible to add a textbox to the upload. How can I create a unique $_POST var for each file the user uploads? Here is the link to the site I am working on: http://epicplank.com/beta/upload/example/

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr class="template-upload{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
    <td class="preview"></td>
    <td class="name">${name}</td>
    <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
    <td class="desc"><!-- Description Textbox here --></td>
</tr>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This post looks like what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787321/jquery-file-upload-specifying-formdata